# Using a MacOS cloud service to develop React Native apps

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, cloud

I've been using Expo to develop React-Native apps for both iOS and Android. However, I now need to use bluetooth, so I need to detach Expo and my app.

As I only have access to Windows/Linux environments, I cannot run Xcode and therefore cannot develop for iOS if I detach from Expo.

Is it possible to use a cloud service (MacinCloud, MacStadium, etc.) in order to develop React-Native apps ? Has anyone succeeded by proceeding with this method ? Thank you.